# Simple icon to represent 'presets'?

Tags: icon, symbols

For my concept I have a task bar that has 3 functions.
'Save' 'Load Preset' and 'Help'.

*Save* and *Help* both have simple icons that don't require text. Which is great, because I would like to leave as much room as possible for the images and many, many items of clothing. The *'load preset'* icon has gotten me into some trouble however.

These are the icons I've tried so far:

[image]

All the feedback I got was mostly negative about these options. The first was perceived to be a filter button. The second was confused for a link to the games section. The third was confused for a link to the closet or maybe even to remove all clothing.

**What would be a better, less confusing way to picture 'Load Preset' or 'Presets'?**

> The concept is of the 'dress up doll' kind. *Save* let's you either publish or save as a preset. *Load presets* will let you load a previous look you've created into a preset. *Help* gives you a small explanation screen. There are some filters and sort buttons too but they are not in direct contact with the task bar. Other features on the site include an inventory and a closet as well as shops and games.

Comment: You could try noun project with keywords  like [preset](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=preset), [load](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=load), [dress](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=dress), [change](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=change) , [store](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=store)... but what about a empty clothes hanger and a full one.

Answer (score 4):

Given the specific nature of the presets you're working with, I'd suggest reconceptualising them from the top, and using *that new concept* to derive the icon - I'm talking about your switching your thinking from "preset" to "outfit" or "costume" or "ensemble"... take the concept you mentioned of the closet, and use that to your advantage: you've a general "closet" for individual clothing items, and an "ensemble closet" for presets - for outfits.

Iconography could be of top on hanger, bottom on hanger and shoes all together with a direction arrow for out from closet and into closet...

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly, the mechanics between the *Save* button and the *Load Presets* is similar as in Photoshop when we take **Snapshots**.

> The Snapshot command lets you make a temporary copy (or snapshot) of any state of the image.

---

> You can compare effects easily. Switch between the snapshots to find the settings you like best.

In your case, instead of *Save* the option should be to take a *Snapshot*, or a *Photo*. The *Load Presets* is to show the *Previous* or the *Original Snapshot*.

This can make it easier to find an iconographic image: for example a camera and a polaroid photo tilted as a previous state. Or just the same icon repeated to show both different states:

[image: states 01]

---

[image: states 02]

As soon as the user start making new changes, the left button turns yellow and the right button gray.

Answer (score 2):

Your client is overthinking it. Your first option can indeed mean [filter](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=filter), but works for [presets](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=preset) just as well. This is a screenshot from Adobe Camera Raw, and honestly these guys probably know better about this than your client. Try to find more examples that would prove this point.

[image]

Otherwise you can try to go a bit more abstract and just show an [up arrow](https://thenounproject.com/search/?q=upload&i=1919418) for 'load' and a down arrow (the same but flipped) for 'save'. No need to be too creative when this stuff is already so overused it becomes the norm.

Its funny when some clients think the whole success of their business hangs on every bit of creative juice they can squeeze.